# Using String values for primary key

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

Can I store `SOF/2015/01` as my ID, and can I auto increment `01` like usual primary key?

Comment: please visit [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996831/custom-primarykey-generation-with-autoincrement) to get a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I store SOF/2015/01 as my ID

Answer : yes you can

> can I auto increment 01 like usual primary key.

Answer : no you can't

Auto increment can increment only numbers.

You have to that manually.

You can use function in trigger to generate your desire auto incremented number like this

```
create function NextCustomerNumber() 
returns char(5) 
as 
begin 
    declare @lastval char(5) 
    set @lastval = (select max(customerNumber) from Customers) 
    if @lastval is null set @lastval = 'C0001' 
    declare @i int 
    set @i = right(@lastval,4) + 1 
    return 'C' + right('000' + convert(varchar(10),@i),4) 
end
```

This can cause some issues, however:

- What if two processes attempt to add a row to the table at the exact
  same time? Can you ensure that the same value is not generated for
  both processes?
- There can be overhead querying the existing data each time you'd like
  to insert new data
- Unless this is implemented as a trigger, this means that all inserts
  to your data must always go through the same stored procedure that
  calculates these sequences. This means that bulk imports, or moving
  data from production to testing and so on, might not be possible or
  might be very inefficient.
- If it is implemented as a trigger, will it work for a set-based
  multi-row INSERT statement? If so, how efficient will it be? This
  function wouldn't work if called for each row in a single set-based
  INSERT -- each NextCustomerNumber() returned would be the same value.

You can learn more from [this](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/custom-auto-generated-sequences-with-sql-server)

Comment: set @i = right(@lastval,4) + 1 
    return 'C' + right('000' + convert(varchar(10),@i),4) 

what does this refer..can you explain with c# code

Answer (score 1):

Create  a  two column unique primary key with the string 'SOF/2015' as part one  and an auto increment-ing  integer as the second column.  You can combine the two columns using a function that returns a string to give you the combined key.   For syntactic  sugar,  you can create a view on the table  using your function to combine the keys into one  view column.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` types as primary keys, on the presumption that any variable-sized columns don't use `MAX`, and data doesn't exceed the maximum allowable size of your index.

As for using it as an auto-incremented column, that won't work. SQL is very smart, but not quite in that way.

I would suggest pulling that string into two or three separate columns, so that you can store the `"01"` portion as a separate, `IDENTITY`'d column. But certainly this is a design question that you'd have to work out on your own.

The other solution would be a trigger, but I'd probably hesitate in general with using something like this as a primary key. Using numeric types is just a lot nicer in many ways, particularly when you have to reference the tables elsewhere. You could always apply a `UNIQUE` index on the string representation.

Comment: In your case if I use several columns for this like this 

course -  SOF
ID - 01